# Bedeutung und Erklärung von »diejenige welche sein«

Tags: meaning, book, relative-pronoun, ellipsis

In einem Kriminalroman fand ich folgenden Satz:

> Das Rätsel um Brookies Tod war nicht durch Fotoapparate oder Notizen zu lösen, sondern im Chemielabor.
>   Und ich würde **diejenige welche sein**.

Mir, als Muttersprachler, ist die Bedeutung von *welche* in dieser Konstruktion ein Rätsel. Nach meiner Auffassung bedeutet der Satz in etwa: »Ich werde diejenige sein, die das Rätsel löst.«

Meine Frage ist also, was für eine Rolle *welche* in dem Satz spielt und was damit im Kontext genau gemeint ist.

Comment: Holprige Übersetzung vielleicht?

Answer (score 3):

Der zitierte Absatz ist sicher kein Geniestreich der deutschen Sprache - "Diejenige welche" wäre sinnvoll verwendbar, wenn im vorherigen Satz ein "jemand" oder eine andere, in irgendeiner Weise nicht näher spezifizierte Person vorkommen würde, auf die sich das Relativpronomen beziehen könnte, z.B.

> ... jemand würde dieses Rätsel im Chemielabor lösen müssen - Und ich würde diejenige welche sein.

Da aber im vorhergehenden Satz überhaupt nicht von einer Person die Rede ist, sondern nur von einem Rätsel, das gewisse Eigenschaften hat, ergibt "diejenige welche" für mich überhaupt keinen Sinn - Aus dem Kontext ist zwar erschließbar, was gemeint ist, aber verständlich ist der Absatz nicht.

Comment: Aufgrund der fehlenden Referenz auf eine Person fände ich auch den Satz *Und ich würde diejenige sein* eher unpassend. Egal ob mit oder ohne zusätzlichem *welche* darin

Answer (score 3):

Formulierungen der Art

> Jemand muss den Saustall aufräumen. Und ich werde derjenige welche sein.

kommen in ironischer oder humoristischer Sprechweise häufiger vor.

Von der Entstehung her handelt es sich um eine Ellipse (Auslassung; eine rhetorische Figur). Im Beispielsatz wäre etwa zu ergänzen

> Jemand muss den Saustall aufräumen. Und ich werde derjenige sein, welche[n es erwischt].

Wer solche Sätze formuliert, rechnet in der Regel damit, dass das Publikum die fehlenden Elemente aus dem Kontext erschließt.

Natürlich könnte man auch einfach sagen

> Jemand muss den Saustall aufräumen. Und das werde natürlich wieder ich sein.

Mit "derjenige welche" klingt es umständlicher und ungelenker. Dies kann, wenn es beabsichtigt ist, einen komischen Effekt haben. Wenn es ohne Absicht geschieht, sondern aus wirklicher sprachlicher Ungeschicklichkeit, ist es natürlich eher ein Mangel.